# Send Email to Attendees(Contacts) from Custom Development

Tags: lightning, email, event, custom, page-override

We override the salesforce standard event creation with custom lightning component, now we're trying to achieve the sending invites to the attendees from our custom development.

We did try to use the salesforce standard email template, seems like there is no email template that they exposed globally.

This is how salesforce standard email sending out to the contact attendees
[image]

On click of the Respond, it is redirecting to the URL under the Respond button, which is salesforce standard page.

[image]

1. Is there anyway to send the same email template from the custom development of EventRelation record creation
2. If 1 is not possible, worst scenario, we can construct the url, seems like oid is organisation id, but how can we construct the aid, it should be definitely an event id. Is it possible to construct the aid?

Any suggestions/solutions are much appreciated